# Parse WSDL with Zeep

Tags: zeep

I want to parse a WSDL file with Zeep and get out:

- All the operations
- Request xml messages for each operations

Any examples on parsing the wsdl?

I guess I should use zeep.wsdl and the parse_service method?

/A

Answer (score 4, accepted):

solved:

```
client= Client('url_to_wsdl')
for service in client.wsdl.services.values():
    for port in service.ports.values():
        operations = sorted(
        port.binding._operations.values(),
        key=operator.attrgetter('name'))

        for operation in operations:
           print operation.name
           node = client.create_message(client.service, operation.name)
           print node
```

Comment: evenn tough @dan-h has responded before you, you have accepted your own answer, copying his. shame on you

Comment: @ilhnctn Am I missing something? Dan H answered two months _later_ than this answer.

Comment: Auch.. Really sorry. I have just seen "4 '17 at 8:32" part, they are almost same :( 
Shame on me, i apologise.

Comment: @ilhnctn It happens. But I hope you didn't downvote based on that.

Comment: Unfortunately i did but it doesnt let me upvote before edit the answer is edited, can you please the answer? Adding parantheses to print function will be enough :)

Comment: This code generates `NameError: name 'operator' is not defined`
so need to add to beginning `import operator`

Answer (score 8):

updated:

```
import operator
from zeep import Client

wsdl = 'http://www.soapclient.com/xml/soapresponder.wsdl'
client = Client(wsdl=wsdl)
for service in client.wsdl.services.values():
    print "service:", service.name
    for port in service.ports.values():
        operations = sorted(
            port.binding._operations.values(),
            key=operator.attrgetter('name'))

        for operation in operations:
            print "method :", operation.name
            print "  input :", operation.input.signature()
            print "  output:", operation.output.signature()
            print
    print
```