# How to handle WSDL Operations not recognized by Zeep

Tags: python, xml, soap, wsdl, zeep

I have a WSDL that zeep shows as having no operations, but there are operations in the WSDL when I pull it up on a browser. For reference, the WSDL requires a certificate. The WSDL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions targetNamespace="http://www.ercot.com/wsdl/2007-06/nodal/ewsConcrete" xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:ns4="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:ns3="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/jms/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:tns="http://www.ercot.com/wsdl/2007-06/nodal/ewsConcrete" xmlns:ns0="http://www.ercot.com/schema/2007-06/nodal/ews/message" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsu="http://www.docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsse="http://www.docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
    <wsp:UsingPolicy xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" wsdl:Required="true" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"/>
    <wsp:Policy xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy"><sp:SecurityHeader MustManifestEncryption="true" MustPrepend="true" xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext"/></wsp:Policy>
    <wsp:Policy wsu:Id="SecurityTokens" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"><wsp:ExactlyOne><wsp:All><sp:SecurityToken xmlns:_ns1="http://www.actional.com" xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext"><sp:TokenType>_ns1:SSLClientCertificate</sp:TokenType></sp:SecurityToken></wsp:All><wsp:All><sp:SecurityToken xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext"><sp:TokenType>sp:X509v3</sp:TokenType></sp:SecurityToken></wsp:All><wsp:All><sp:SecurityToken xmlns:_ns1="http://www.actional.com" xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext"><sp:TokenType>_ns1:SSLClientCertificate</sp:TokenType></sp:SecurityToken><sp:SecurityToken xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext"><sp:TokenType>sp:X509v3</sp:TokenType></sp:SecurityToken></wsp:All></wsp:ExactlyOne></wsp:Policy>
    <wsp:Policy wsu:Id="SignedBody" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"><sp:Integrity xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext"><sp:TokenInfo><sp:SecurityToken><sp:TokenType>sp:X509v3</sp:TokenType></sp:SecurityToken></sp:TokenInfo><sp:MessageParts>wsp:GetBody(.)</sp:MessageParts></sp:Integrity></wsp:Policy>
    <wsp:Policy wsu:Id="Alerts_input_policy" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"><wsp:PolicyReference URI="#SecurityTokens"/><wsp:PolicyReference URI="#SignedBody"/></wsp:Policy>
    <wsp:Policy wsu:Id="Alerts_output_policy" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"><wsp:PolicyReference URI="#SignedBody"/></wsp:Policy>
    <wsp:Policy wsu:Id="MarketInfo_input_policy" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"><wsp:PolicyReference URI="#SecurityTokens"/><wsp:PolicyReference URI="#SignedBody"/></wsp:Policy>
    <wsp:Policy wsu:Id="MarketInfo_output_policy" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"><wsp:PolicyReference URI="#SignedBody"/></wsp:Policy>
    <wsp:Policy wsu:Id="MarketTransactions_input_policy" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"><wsp:PolicyReference URI="#SecurityTokens"/><wsp:PolicyReference URI="#SignedBody"/></wsp:Policy>
    <wsp:Policy wsu:Id="MarketTransactions_output_policy" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"><wsp:PolicyReference URI="#SignedBody"/></wsp:Policy>
  <types>
    <xsd:complexType xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="RequestType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="MarketType">
                <xsd:simpleType>
                    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                        <xsd:enumeration value="DAM"/>
                        <xsd:enumeration value="ADJ"/>
                        <xsd:enumeration value="RTM"/>
                    </xsd:restriction>
                </xsd:simpleType>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="OperatingDate" type="xsd:dateTime"/>
            <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="TradingDate" type="xsd:date"/>
            <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="StartTime" type="xsd:dateTime"/>
            <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="EndTime" type="xsd:dateTime"/>
            <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="Zone" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="ASType" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="Option" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="SortBy" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="ID" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:any maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" namespace="##other"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:complexType xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="ReplyType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="ReplyCode" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="Error" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="Timestamp" type="xsd:dateTime"/>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="ID" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:any maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" namespace="##other"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:complexType xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="PayloadType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:choice>
                <xsd:any maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" namespace="##other" processContents="skip"/>
                <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="Document" type="xsd:string"/>
                <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="Compressed" type="xsd:string"/>
            </xsd:choice>
            <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="format" type="xsd:string"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:complexType xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="ReplayDetectionType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="Nonce" type="wsse:EncodedString"/>
            <xsd:element name="Created" type="wsu:AttributedDateTime"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:complexType xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="HeaderType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element default="get" name="Verb">
                <xsd:simpleType>
                    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                        <xsd:enumeration value="cancel"/>
                        <xsd:enumeration value="canceled"/>
                        <xsd:enumeration value="change"/>
                        <xsd:enumeration value="changed"/>
                        <xsd:enumeration value="create"/>
                        <xsd:enumeration value="created"/>
                        <xsd:enumeration value="close"/>
                        <xsd:enumeration value="closed"/>
                        <xsd:enumeration value="delete"/>
                        <xsd:enumeration value="deleted"/>
                        <xsd:enumeration value="get"/>
                        <xsd:enumeration value="reply"/>
                        <xsd:enumeration value="submit"/>
                        <xsd:enumeration value="update"/>
                        <xsd:enumeration value="updated"/>
                    </xsd:restriction>
                </xsd:simpleType>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="Noun" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="ReplayDetection" type="ReplayDetectionType"/>
            <xsd:element default="001" name="Revision" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="Source" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="UserID" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="MessageID" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="Comment" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:any maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" namespace="##other"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:element xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="Message">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="Header" type="HeaderType"/>
                <xsd:choice>
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="Request" type="RequestType"/>
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="Reply" type="ReplyType"/>
                </xsd:choice>
                <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="Payload" type="PayloadType"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
    <xsd:element xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="RequestMessage">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="Header" type="HeaderType"/>
                <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="Request" type="RequestType"/>
                <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="Payload" type="PayloadType"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
    <xsd:element xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="ResponseMessage">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="Header" type="HeaderType"/>
                <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="Reply" type="ReplyType"/>
                <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="Payload" type="PayloadType"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
    <xsd:element xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="FaultMessage">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="Reply" type="ReplyType"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
  </types>
  <message name="EWSRequest">
    <part name="input" element="ns0:RequestMessage"/>
  </message>
  <message name="EWSResponse">
    <part name="output" element="ns0:ResponseMessage"/>
  </message>
  <message name="EWSFault">
    <part name="fault" element="ns0:FaultMessage"/>
  </message>
  <portType name="Operations">
    <operation name="MarketTransactions">
      <input message="tns:EWSRequest"/>
      <output message="tns:EWSResponse"/>
      <fault name="fault1" message="tns:EWSFault"/>
    </operation>
    <operation name="Alerts">
      <input message="tns:EWSRequest"/>
      <output message="tns:EWSResponse"/>
      <fault name="fault1" message="tns:EWSFault"/>
    </operation>
    <operation name="MarketInfo">
      <input message="tns:EWSRequest"/>
      <output message="tns:EWSResponse"/>
      <fault name="fault1" message="tns:EWSFault"/>
    </operation>
  </portType>
  <binding name="HttpEndPointBinding" type="tns:Operations">
    <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <operation name="MarketTransactions">
      <soap:operation soapAction="/BusinessService/NodalService.serviceagent/HttpEndPoint/MarketTransactions" style="document"/>
      <input>
        <soap:body parts="input" use="literal"/>
    <wsp:PolicyReference xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" URI="#MarketTransactions_input_policy"/>
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body parts="output" use="literal"/>
    <wsp:PolicyReference xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" URI="#MarketTransactions_output_policy"/>
      </output>
      <fault name="fault1">
        <soap:fault name="fault1" use="literal"/>
      </fault>
    </operation>
    <operation name="MarketInfo">
      <soap:operation soapAction="/BusinessService/NodalService.serviceagent/HttpEndPoint/MarketInfo" style="document"/>
      <input>
        <soap:body parts="input" use="literal"/>
    <wsp:PolicyReference xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" URI="#MarketInfo_input_policy"/>
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body parts="output" use="literal"/>
    <wsp:PolicyReference xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" URI="#MarketInfo_output_policy"/>
      </output>
      <fault name="fault1">
        <soap:fault name="fault1" use="literal"/>
      </fault>
    </operation>
    <operation name="Alerts">
      <soap:operation soapAction="/BusinessService/NodalService.serviceagent/HttpEndPoint/Alerts" style="document"/>
      <input>
        <soap:body parts="input" use="literal"/>
    <wsp:PolicyReference xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" URI="#Alerts_input_policy"/>
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body parts="output" use="literal"/>
    <wsp:PolicyReference xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" URI="#Alerts_output_policy"/>
      </output>
      <fault name="fault1">
        <soap:fault name="fault1" use="literal"/>
      </fault>
    </operation>
  </binding>
  <service name="NodalService">
    <port name="HttpEndPoint" binding="tns:HttpEndPointBinding">
      <soap:address location="http://prl0161.ercot.com:8090/sst/runtime.asvc/com.ercot.eip.EWSExtHTTP"/>
    </port>
  </service>
</definitions>
```

I used SOAPUI to test the WSDL and all operations were recognized without any issues, but in python there are a bunch of warnings regarding invalid xsd types. I'm fairly inexperienced with WSDL/XML so those don't mean much to me.  My code is below:

```
import random
from requests import Session
from zeep import Client , Settings
from zeep.transports import Transport
from zeep.wsse.signature import Signature
from suds.wsse import Timestamp
import operator

wsdl_url = r"https://misapi.ercot.com/2007-08/Nodal/eEDS/EWS/?WSDL"
api_base_url = "https://misapi.ercot.com/2007-08/Nodal/eEDS/EWS/"
client_cert_pfx ='pfx path'
client_cert_pem = 'pem path'
keyfile = 'key'
certfile = 'cert'


##############################################################################
def get_random_number():
    rand_numb = random.randint(1000000000000000,9999999999999999)
    return rand_numb
##############################################################################

session = Session()
session.cert = client_cert_pem
transport = Transport(session=session)
signature = Signature(key_file=keyfile, certfile=certfile)

client = Client(
    wsdl=wsdl_url,
    transport=transport,
    wsse=signature
)

request_data = {
    "Header": {
        "Verb": "get",
        "Noun": "SystemStatus",
        "ReplayDetection": {
            "Nonce": get_random_number(),
            "Created": Timestamp().created},
        "Revision": "01",
        "Source": api_base_url,
        "UserID": "UserID",
        "MessageID": "00000000000",
        "Comment": "00000000000",
    },
}


#Code Below is from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50089400/introspecting-a-wsdl-with-# python-zeep

for service in client.wsdl.services.values():
    print("service:", service.name)
    for port in service.ports.values():
        operations = sorted(
            port.binding._operations.values(),
            key=operator.attrgetter('name'))

        for operation in operations:
            print("method :", operation.name)
            print("  input :", operation.input.signature())
            print()
    print()
```

Output:

```
C:\path
-packages\zeep\wsdl\wsdl.py:338: UserWarning: The wsdl:message for '{http://www.ercot.com/wsdl/2007-06/nodal/ewsConcrete}EWSRequest' contains an invalid part ('input'): invalid xsd type or elements
  warnings.warn(str(exc))
C:\path
-packages\zeep\wsdl\wsdl.py:338: UserWarning: The wsdl:message for '{http://www.ercot.com/wsdl/2007-06/nodal/ewsConcrete}EWSResponse' contains an invalid part ('output'): invalid xsd type or elements
  warnings.warn(str(exc))
C:\path
-packages\zeep\wsdl\wsdl.py:338: UserWarning: The wsdl:message for '{http://www.ercot.com/wsdl/2007-06/nodal/ewsConcrete}EWSFault' contains an invalid part ('fault'): invalid xsd type or elements
  warnings.warn(str(exc))
service: NodalService

C:\path
-packages\zeep\wsdl\definitions.py:137: UserWarning: The wsdl:operation 'MarketTransactions' was not found in the wsdl:portType '{http://www.ercot.com/wsdl/2007-06/nodal/ewsConcrete}Operations'
  warnings.warn(str(exc))
C:\path
-packages\zeep\wsdl\definitions.py:137: UserWarning: The wsdl:operation 'MarketInfo' was not found in the wsdl:portType '{http://www.ercot.com/wsdl/2007-06/nodal/ewsConcrete}Operations'
  warnings.warn(str(exc))
C:\path
-packages\zeep\wsdl\definitions.py:137: UserWarning: The wsdl:operation 'Alerts' was not found in the wsdl:portType '{http://www.ercot.com/wsdl/2007-06/nodal/ewsConcrete}Operations'
  warnings.warn(str(exc))
Forcing soap:address location to HTTPS

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Were you ever able to sort this out? If you could post what you found as an answer, I'd be much obliged!

Comment: I was not, at least not with the API. we went the route of straight scraping the website to get the same information. Are you also trying ERCOT? Or just a similar situation for something else?

Comment: Any other ideas where I could look into?